# Pin It Button on Tumblr Posts

Tags: html, tumblr, pinterest

**Goal:** I want to add a "pin it" button (alongside the facebook and twitter buttons) at the bottom of each post on my tumblr.

**Main Problem:** Simply pasting the code provided at http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ for adding a pin it button into tumblr's custom HTML editor does not work. I pasted the following code at the end of the {block:Posts} block:

```
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" class="pin-it-button" 
    count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

This results in a "pin it" button in the correct place in each post, but clicking on it does nothing. The HTML generated by tumblr is changed, and looks as follows:

```
    <a style="cursor:pointer" title="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

There is no href attribute in the anchor tag generated by Tumblr. This seems like a problem. Anyone know how to get Tumblr to do this correctly?

**Another Problem** (Possibly as important): The code provided by pinterest doesn't specify an image to pin. I want the button to pin the image in the post. From reading online I've gotten ideas to include the url and media parameters in the href attribute. For Example:

```
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Permalink}&media={PhotoURL-500}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
    </a>
```

Again, nothing happens when I click the resulting pin it button - so I don't know if these parameters are necessary - only that they don't fix my first problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
- David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. Here's what ended up working for me.

Followed the instructions at http://tumblring.net/how-to-add-a-pinterest-button-to-tumblr/
with the following differences:

1. Used the following HTML embed code right before the {/block:Posts} closing tag:

   ```
   <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Permalink}&media={PhotoURL-500}"
   class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
   <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
   </a>
   ```
2. Did NOT include the following javascript snipped along with the html embed:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the variables in using URLEncodedPermalink - this worked for me:

```
{block:Posts}

  {block:Photo}
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={URLEncodedPermalink}&media={URLEncodedPhotoURL-500}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
   </a>
  {/block:Photo}

{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: This would be the correct answer. You need to `URLEncoded` any information that is being adding into the href.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inside the Posts Block and Post type Block as well. For example if you are adding a pinit button into a photo post it would be the following:

```
{block:Posts}

{block:Photo}
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Permalink}&media={PhotoURL-500}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
    </a>
{/block:Photo}

{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: Hi yamill - thanks for the response. Moving the code snippet so that it resides in both the posts and photo blocks did not fix the issue. The resulting button still does not link anywhere when clicked, the html anchor tag Tumblr generates still has not href.

Comment: Hmm...strange. Can you copy and paste your theme code if you don't mind? Maybe that will help debug.